# How to call the inbuilt feature of Kendo listbox out side the control

Tags: kendo-ui

I am using Kendo ListBox in my application where it has the two data list namely as 'fromData' and 'toData', also it has four in built button controls as  tools: [`"transferTo"`, `"transferFrom"`, `"transferAllTo"`, `"transferAllFrom"`].
when we click on any of the button, the data rendering on the front end acts accordingly. My requirement is - I have added another check box on the page and whenever the checkbox is checked by the user I want the `transferAllTo` to act and all the data should be transferred  from 1st list to 2nd list without clicking on the tool button. It should work only with the selection of check box.

I can see there is a method called `OnRemove()` which is acting when I am clicking the button from front end, so I created a method to be called on `Onclick` event of Checkbox and Inside that I called the `OnRemove()` method but it did not work.

```js
$('#' + clientId).find('#' + fromEntitySelect).kendoListBox({
    draggable: true,
    dataSource: fromDataSource,
    connectWith: "toEntitySelect",
    dropSources: ["toEntitySelect"],
    dataTextField: "Entity",
    dataValueField: "EntityID",
    toolbar: {
        tools: ["transferTo", "transferFrom", "transferAllTo", "transferAllFrom"]
    },
    change: onChange,
    drop: onDrop,
    drag: onDrag,
    dragend: onDragEnd,
    remove: onRemove,
});
```

My requirement is - I have added another check box on the page and whenever the checkbox is checked by the user I want the `transferAllTo` to act and all the data should be transferred  from 1st list to 2nd list without clicking on the tool button. It should work only with the selection of check box.

Comment: What a strange requirement. What should happen if the checkbox is unchecked? Move everything back? What do you mean with "It should work only with the selection of check box." It should not work if the user clicks on the button "transferAllTo"?

Comment: I agree. It is little strange. And Yes, If the checkbox is unchecked then move all the data list item back to left datalist. And I mean there is already a small button which does the transferaAllTo but, even without clicking this button, only with the checkbox check it should also work. Means it should transfer all the datalist Item from left panel to right panel. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simple let jQuery click the button "transferAllTo".

As an example, go to https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/listbox/index and execute `$("a[data-command='transferAllTo']").click()` in the browser's JavaScript console.